# ENVIO DE REQUISIÇÃO PUT COM PHP E GUZZLE

Tags: php, laravel, request, guzzle

Preciso de uma ajudinha de vocês.
Tenho tentado enviar requisições do método PUT através de um Json utilizando o Guzzle, mas sempre obtenho o erro de TRUNCATED ou:

> {   "message": "cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read
> data remaining (see
> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",   "code":
> 500 }

Seria correto fazer o request PUT dessa forma?

```
$reqProduto = $this->client->request('PUT', 'company-products/'.$params['id'], [
                    "headers" => [
                        "Authorization"=> "Bearer ".$this->authToken['token'],
                    ],
                    "json" => [
                        $params
                    ]
                ]);
```

Bom, pessoal. Consegui resolver o problema. Coisinha simples.
O fato era que eu estava passando o $params dentro de colchetes, e o acabou que quando tirei os colchetes e deixei o array apenas `"json" => $params` funcionou e resolveu o probleminha.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente Sim!

```
$r = $this->client->request('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put', [
    'headers' => [
         'Authorization'=> "Bearer ".$this->authToken['token'],
     ],
     'json' => [
         'foo' => 'bar'
     ]
]);
```

De uma olhada na propria documentação do Guzzle
https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/index.html

E de também uma olhada neste blog que cita o mesmo problema
https://bobcares.com/blog/curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/

Comment: Obrigado, Fernando! Consegui resolver o problema.
Eu estava passando `"json" => [$params]` ao invés de `"json" => $params`.